# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - not JQuery

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I feel terrible for submitting another **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function** question. But after reading about 20 different answers to these types of questions, either I am missing the point, or the problem was different in those cases.

I have a form with two radio buttons. When one is clicked I want it to change the innerHTML of a `<tr></tr>` tag.

Here is my [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MowgliB/van5S/5/).

The HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" autocomplete="off" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="mode">Text</label>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="text" id="setText" />
<label for="mode">Image</label>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="img" id="setImg" />
<table>
<tr id="headerInput"></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("setText").addEventListener("click", function () {
window.getElementById("headerInput").innerHTML = '<td>Title</td><td><input type="text" name="title" value="Hello" /></td>';
});
document.getElementById("setImg").addEventListener("click", function () {
window.getElementById("headerInput").innerHTML = '<td>Banner</td><td><input type="file" name="banner" /></td>';
});
```

I have tried a few different versions of the same thing, like creating named functions, using the `onclick="someFunction()"` attribute and `object.onclick` as well. All of them give me the same error. Your help to understand what I am doing is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.getElementById()` isn't defined normally in a browser.

Looking up property `'getElementById'` on `window` returns `undefined`. You're then attempting to invoke `undefined`, hence *Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function*.

You probably mean to use `document` there instead.

Comment: It's amazing how you can overlook something even though I read through the code at least 30 times before submitting a question. One of those things that just takes experience or fresh eyes to spot.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer document.getElementById() rather than window.getElementById(). Also, changing the innerHTML is fine but afaik we should refer to the td inside the tr for any manipulations. That's a best practice.

```
document.getElementById("headerInput").innerHTML
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fpBg/